# Php to Xml - Remove a text part from a result

Tags: php, xml, wordpress

i have the code i will show next:

```
$xml->startElement("description");
  $xml->writeRaw(utf8_encode(strip_tags($row['post_content'],'')));
  $xml->endElement();
```

and this bring me a result like

```
<description>A M21Rh – Empresa de Trabalho Temporário, Lda recruta para empresa sua cliente, Eng. de Sistemas de Energias para a zona de Aveiro.

Perfil:
- Dinamismo;
- Responsável;
- Pontual;

Requisitos:
- Domínio da Ferramenta MCAD (CATIA V5, AUTOCAD);
- Conhecimentos Sólidos de MS Office;
- Conhecimento de VBA (Preferencial);
- Fluência da Língua Inglesa (Escrito e Falado);
- Alemão ou Mandarim( Falado);
- Disponibilidade para viajar;

Oferecemos:
- Pacote Salarial compatível com a função e desempenho;
Responder a esta oferta
[si-contact-form form='4']</description>
```

in the end of the text i always get the shortcode from a wordpress plugin that i'm using. I would like to know how i can remove it. I also need to remove the line "Responder a esta oferta"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just replace that code?

```
$content = utf8_encode(strip_tags($row['post_content'],'')); 
$text_to_replace = "[si-contact-form form='4']";
$replace_to = '';
$result_content = str_replace($text_to_replace,$replace_to,$content);

  $xml->startElement("description");
  $xml->writeRaw($result_content);
  $xml->endElement();
```

Comment: i really dont know what to do since i'm really new to programming. I will try this solution. Thanks

Comment: I just noticed it now. I need to remove "Responder a esta oferta
[si-contact-form form='4']" but when i add it to the code you gave me it doesn't work